# What is the classification of the words such as "group of", "bundle of", "number of" and also the right form of verb after using this words?

Tags: verb-agreement, parts-of-speech, quantifiers

#### First example:

1. > A bundle of roses is the most beautiful thing one can have in the morning.
2. > A bundle of roses are the most beautiful thing ...

#### Second example:

1. > The number of books are four.
2. > The number of books is four.

---

Which of the above sentences are correct?

Comment: These are called quantifiers. Typically, the verb agrees with the quantifier, as it is syntactically the head of the noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

"Bundle" and "(the) number" are collectives, or *collective nouns.*

> A bundle of roses is the most beautiful thing one can have

is correct, as "a bundle" is a singular thing, even if composed of many parts. "Bundles" would be plural.

> The number of books is four.

"The number" will always be singular, as it refers to a specific quantity. The article "the" limits "number" to one specific thing.

"A number" will always be plural, as the reference is to an indefinite quantity.   "The number" is a collective, however "a number" is better classed a *quantifier.*

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first example, the former is the grammatically correct sentence. The word “bundle” is not necessarily a quantifier, as the official definition of one – in relation to grammar – is “a determiner or pronoun indicative of quantity; *e.g.*, *all*, *both*”. However, a collective noun – a noun that denotes a group of individuals; *e.g.*, *assembly*, *family*, *crew* – is an accurate term for it.

As for the subsequent nouns, those are modifiers placed through the conjunction *of*. These nouns do not represent the entire mass or quantity; ergo, they are not the “head noun” and should not be considered when deciding whether or not it would be appropriate to conjugate the verb *be* to its corresponding singular form or its corresponding plural form (*i.e.*, *is* or *was*, compared to *are* or *were*).

Basically, when using conjunctions, the generic rule is to ignore the conjunctive phrase.

> A bundle of roses is the most beautiful thing one can have in the morning.

Compare this to the sentence, “A bundle of roses are the most beautiful thing . . .”

The “bundle” is the main object, and although it consists of roses, the roses themselves *are not* the specified nouns. Due to this, the subsequent verb is singular.

Comment: By the way, "bundle" is not the word generally used with roses or other flowers.  "A bunch of roses" or, even better, "a bouquet of roses" (or other flowers) would be preferable in this example.  But the principle is the same as that described above for "bundle, namely, since "bunch" and "bouquet" are both singular, you would use "...*is* the most beautiful thing...."

Comment: You could though say that a “bundle of roses are ..” but in that case you’d be indicating that the bundle is metaphoric